# How can I remove oil spots from kitchen floor?

Tags: oil, cleaning, kitchen

Sometimes during cooking oil drops falls in floor, and look ugly. How can I remove these types of oil spots from floor?

Comment: What is the floor surface made of?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about cleaning, not cooking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are worried about stains a degreaser will help. There are many soaps on the market that will work in this context. It is important to clean it quick so the stain doesn't have time to get worse. Bleach can help with stains after the fact but can also leave splotching so may not work for you.

If on the other hand, if you are referring to the slipperiness that comes with grease on the floor, salt works well. Pour salt on the grease then sweep it up with a broom. Degreaser also works again in this situation. Just add a little to your mop water.

Answer (score 0):

Sprinkle with cornstarch, allow some time to absorb the grease, then either sweep or vacuum it up.